# Is Action Center any different in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I always turned off Action Center in Windows 7 - is there anything new in Windows 8 worth keeping it around for?

Comment: Action Center is also where [Defender-related messages show up now](http://superuser.com/a/494274/138343), since there's no separate tray icon anymore as there was for MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Action center (in Windows 8) also now reports if applications are impacting startup time.  That's a good enough reason for me to leave it enabled, but obviously your own situation may be different.

Comment: You can check from time to time in the Task Manager in the Startup tab, though, which shows the same.

Comment: @Joey, agreed, but that means remembering to check, while the Action Center report prompts me to look --- for me, that's a good enough reason to leave it active!

Answer (score 1):

From [Keep tabs on performance in Windows 8 with Action Center](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/keep-tabs-on-performance-in-windows-8-with-action-center/6422) on TechRepublic:

> **Windows SmartScreen**
>
> Designed to provide protection against phishing Web sites and
>   malicious downloads
>
> **Windows Activation**
>
> Clicking the View activation details takes you to a Control Panel
>   applet
>
> In addition to the activation details, you can use the links to
>   purchase additional copies of Windows 8 or learn more about the
>   license terms
>
> **Microsoft account**
>
> The Microsoft account feature links your Windows 8 user account with
>   what is currently called Windows Live and is designed to seamlessly
>   provide access to all sorts of features in the cloud, such as photos,
>   documents, and other files from places like SkyDrive, Facebook, and
>   Flickr. You can also share status and contact info with Hotmail,
>   Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn. Of course, this is all optional and
>   configurable
>
> **Automatic Maintenance**
>
> This feature that will automatically perform maintenance tasks such as
>   software updates, security scans and system diagnostics. If you click
>   Change Maintenance Settings, you can choose the time that you want the
>   Automatic Maintenance
>
> **File History**
>
> File History is a new feature in Windows 8 that works like a
>   combination of Previous Versions and Windows Backup and Restore

It's up to you to decide if you keep it or not.

Comment: Please, if you have to copy and paste from other articles, embed text you didn't write yourself in blockquotes (e.g. with `Ctrl-Q`). Moreover it would be preferable to describe in your own words rather than copying large passages from other sites.