# What are 'Toasts' or 'Toast Notifications' in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, notifications, terminology

I have seen the term 'Toast' used in the Windows 8 context. I have also seen them referred to as 'Toast Notifications'.

What exactly are 'Toasts' in Windows 8?

Comment: Also see [How to disable popup messages in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/491354/how-to-disable-popup-messages-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 8 has a notification system similar to that implemented in mobile operation systems such as Android, IOS and Windows Phone.

A Windows 8 Toast is a notification triggered by an application or the operating system itself that is displayed to thew user by way of a small pop-up notification.

[Wikipedia defines a Toast in the computing context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_%28computing%29) as:

> A toast is a small, informational window displayed by certain kinds of
>   software, especially instant messaging clients such as AOL Instant
>   Messenger, Windows Live Messenger, XFire and Trillian. Toasts notify
>   users of various kinds of events, such as reception of new e-mail, a
>   change in a peer's availability, or a change in network connectivity.

Toasts in Windows 8 comprise of a short text message and can optionally include a small image.

[image: Windows 8 Toast with image]

More technical info [here](http://davidburela.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/windows-8-demo-toast-notifications/).

Answer (score 2):

They are "pop-ups".  They pop-up like slices from the toaster.  The name will mean little to the many peope who make toast under the grill.

Comment: IMO, this type of popup is annoying. It is arguably relevant if the app itself is running or if the OS reports something relevant to a user action, but otherwise just clutter.