# Keep "toast" notifications up until I close them?

Tags: windows-8, notifications, popups

I want the toast notifications to stay up until I:

- Hover over the toast
- Click on it (it currently closes after this)
- Click the X (also, currently closes after this)

Basically, keep it open until I interact with it.

For those of you who didn't know (I didn't know it was a "toast" until someone told me), a toast is this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, almost the exact opposite of [my question](http://superuser.com/questions/491354/how-to-disable-popup-messages-in-windows-8)! :)

Comment: Figured it out, there's a registry key you have to edit.

Comment: ad which key was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast notifications are not designed to stay on screen all the time so don't use them to display important data:

> Don't use toast notifications to notify the user of something that
>   must be seen, such as a critical alert. To ensure that the user has
>   seen your message, notify them in the context of your app with a
>   Flyout, dialog, app bar, or other inline element.

You can increase the display time in the modern pc settings tool

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx

Comment: Right, but I don't look up to the top-right up my screen very often. I want to be notified of everything that happens, so in my case it'd be useful. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party - as of 2016, you can use a "reminder" scenario to cause a toast to stay visible.  See [the docs at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts#alarms-reminders-and-incoming-calls):

> A reminder toast notification will stay on screen until the user dismisses it or takes action.